# Not showing Dynamic Form submission tokens in workflow for sending message

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I have created a `dynamic form` with three field: Name, Email, Message. Its not bind to any content type,only stores submissions.

In workflow in body of message for sending email, I want to use tokens to display the values of the dynamic form fields. I tried some made up tokens but didn't worked. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will let you access the field value by field name:

```
{FormSubmission.Field:Your Field Name}
```

and you can use it to build your email, as following:

```
Name: {FormSubmission.Field:Name}<br/>
Email: {FormSubmission.Field:Email}<br/>
Message: {FormSubmission.Field:Message}<br/>
```

Note: be sure that you set the same name for the field in layout editor.